# import-jdl fails when pasring entities

Tags: jhipster, jdl

JHipster 7.7.0

I am trying to import the following JDL file:

```
entity UploadedResource {
    fileName String required,
    owner String required,
    uploadedBy String required,
    uploadTime Instant required,
    description String,
    fileSize Long,
    content Blob
}

entity SharedResource {
    resource UploadedResource required,
    url String required,
    public Boolean
}

entity ResourceDownload {
    resource UploadedResource required,
    downloadTime Instant required,
    user String
}

enum Language {
    ENGLISH, GERMAN, SPANISH, HUNGARIAN, ROMANIAN
}

relationship OneToOne {
    SharedResource{resource} to UploadedResource
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    ResourceDownload{resource} to UploadedResource
}

paginate UploadedResource with pagination

dto * with mapstruct

service all with serviceImpl
```

The import fails with the following error:

[image: unknown field type]

JDL Studio renders the relations correctly. Also, if I use the built in entity User, it complains about it too.
If I only leave the UploadedResource entity and remove the others and the relationships, it works fine, the entity is created and I can use it in the application.

What could be the reason of the error message?
No other entities are loaded into the application.

Answer (score 1):

The generator complains because you are mixing up entity and relationship definitions. It's better if `entity` blocks contain only [field](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#field-types-and-validations) or [enumerated](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/enums) types, and `relationship` blocks contain entity [relationships](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/relationships).

This should work:

```
entity UploadedResource {
    fileName String required,
    owner String required,
    uploadedBy String required,
    uploadTime Instant required,
    description String,
    fileSize Long,
    content Blob
}

entity SharedResource {
    url String required,
    isPublic Boolean
}

entity ResourceDownload {
    downloadTime Instant required,
    user String
}

enum Language {
    ENGLISH, GERMAN, SPANISH, HUNGARIAN, ROMANIAN
}

relationship OneToOne {
    SharedResource{resource required} to UploadedResource
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    ResourceDownload{resource required} to UploadedResource
}

paginate UploadedResource with pagination

dto * with mapstruct

service all with serviceImpl
```

Another small problem is that you used `public` as a field name in `SharedResource` but this is a reserved keyword in Java, I changed it to `isPublic`.

I also added the `required` flag to both of your relationship definitions since it seems that is what you were trying to do.